# Does the Census Bureau's geocoding API limit request frequency?

Tags: geocoding, batch, api, united-states, census

I am trying to batch-geocode about 8 million address records using the Census Bureau's batch geocoder. I am currently doing so sequentially, which takes about a day to complete. I was considering trying to parallelize this process, but I wasn't sure if the Census Bureau's API allowed requests with such frequency. Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Have you seen this file: https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.pdf. It says there *"There is currently an upper limit of 10,000 records per batch file."*

Comment: Check also this page: https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/technical-documentation/complete-technical-documentation/census-geocoder.html